# JWT Authentication and authorization without using api controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to make login with JWT authentication. But wherever i find the way of use it always use with api but I do not want to use api i just want to creat just separate controller for login.Kindly tell me how to authorize with jwt and without api.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description,if you want to enable the JWT authentication for MVC, I suggest you could follow this [article](https://www.codemag.com/Article/2105051/Implementing-JWT-Authentication-in-ASP.NET-Core-5).

The difference between the JWT authentication for the MVC and Web API is you need store the token at somewhere, since the web api you need to set the token inside the Authorization header for each request.

To solve this issue, you could follow the article which I shared, it store the token inside the session and then it will write a middleware which will read the token from session and then set it at the request header.

The middleware like this.

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var token = context.Session.GetString("Token");
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
    {
        context.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    }
    await next();
});
```

For store the token, you could write you own codes and then using the [session storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to store the token.

```
     HttpContext.Session.SetString("Token", generatedToken);
```